# Using sed to copy one line to another

Tags: sed

I need to replace a line (4) with a copy of another line (6) in a range of files.

So far I know how to return a single line (although returns with carriage return?)...

```
sed -n '6p' *
```

also this doesn't work with * for files, only seems to return the first file.

And I can also replace a line with some chars...

```
sed -i '5s/.*/  00/' *
```

But I cannot figure out how to do both together.

Edit: One step closer but now need to apply to multiple files (in the same folder). * reads in the first file only.

```
sed -i '4s/.*/sed -n '6p' file.nc/e' file.nc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -Ei  '4{:a;N;6!ba;s/^[^\n]*(\n.*\n(.*))/\2\1/}' file1 file2 file3 fileetc
```

Gather up lines between line 4 and 6 and then replace line 4 by line 6.

---

Alternative:

```
sed '4d;5,6{H;5h;6!d;G}' file
```

Delete line 4 (not needed).

In the range between lines 5 and 6, append a copy of line 6 to a copy of line 5 and append those copies to line 6.

Comment: This worked thanks, I thought I had it before but I was replacing the wrong direction and couldn't figure out how to swap it again. (sed -i '4h; 6x' *)